# Is there any performance hit for setting an element's style to the value it already has? Or do all browsers just ignore it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

If I have an element with style `top: 5px`, and I call `element.style.top = "5px";` will the browser reposition it and run "layout" again? Or does it know to not change anything? (is this in the W3C standards?)

Why?

I'm setting some values based on scrolling. For example, from a `scrollTop` of 100 to 300, an element should change it's `top` from `25px` to `50px`.

If the user scrolls a little quickly, it could jump from a `scrollTop` of 285 to 310. That means the element will not be at `50px` but instead at `48.125px`.

To counteract this, I set all scroll values above 300 to make that element's top be `50px`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for all browsers but in Chrome: setting an element's css property to an identical value (or one that will not change its appearance) will not cause a redraw. Here are a couple good resources for learning: [HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/) & [phpied](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)

To test this: go into Chrome's Developer tools setting menu (three dots in the top right) and in "More tools" click on "Rendering settings"

[image]

Then check "Enable paint flashing"

[image]

Then create a blank page with the following code (note: this will NOT work in iframes because their criteria for redrawing are different, ie the code snippet viewer will not illustrate my point):

```js
  window.onscroll = function(){
 document.body.style.background="yellow";
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 200vh;
  }
```

When you scroll you will notice only the scroll bar is flashing in green (meaning it is being redrawn). If you instead set the opacity of the body to say `.000000000000001` and `onscroll` to add `.000000000000001` to the opacity it will redraw the body every scroll until the opacity hits >=1.

Comment: Thank you. In Chrome it doesn't continue to turn green, *but* it does still take more time than an empty for loop. So there is some (minor) penalty for attempting to set the value, but it's small (except in IE/Edge where it's not quite as small)